# inoutstream from a website displays nothing

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

i used the following code to read line by line from a website using textview. But the problem is the textview displays nothing.

I would like to know where my mistake is or how to correct my code to read data from a website.

To Note: i use the emulator.

JAVA Code:

```
try {
          URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
          HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          con.setDoOutput(true);
          con.connect();
          //readStream(con.getInputStream());
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (con.getInputStream()));
          String line="";
        while ( (line=reader.readLine()) != null)
            tv00.setText(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: would u please tell me what is the difference between log and settext

Comment: i am not sure what is tv00, but if it is textView then you are overwriting previously recieved data. So if the last recieved line is empty, you will get a empty textView. If you use log, you can atleast check whether you have recieved any data

Comment: can u please tell me how to use log instead of settext

Comment: Log.e("TAG",""+line);  and check the logcat output

Comment: i did as u suggested, and i checked the logcat error and verbose and the other things and there were no output

Comment: is it printing any exception?

Comment: logcat error displays nothing